# Убрать строку заголовка в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Хочу написать клиент (лаунчер) для своей игры, но мне хочется иметь красивый дизайн и чтоб вверху не было строки с белым фоном и кнопочками справа. Подскажите как её убрать полностью, в WinForms это делается очень просто, убрав border у окна, а WPF всё не так то и просто. Нашёл несколько тем тут и попробовал, но осталась всего лишь белая линия. Ещё когда увидел эту белую линию вспомнил торрент MediaGet и подумал, что все мои шансы упали к нулю.

Comment: Скажи мне просто возможно ли это.

Comment: Чтобы убрать верхнюю шапку добавь AllowsTransparency="False" WindowStyle="None"